# Singular or plural after "by"

Tags: grammatical-number

Question:

> They are categorized/grouped by the generation **mechanism or
> mechanisms**?

I am not sure which one should be used after "by", singular or plural?

Intuitively, I would use the plural as there are more than one mechanisms. But I realised people often say a population can be grouped by an attribute, e.g. gender, age. I am confused. Would you please help me?

Thanks

Comment: How many mechanisms are there in a group?

Comment: For example, I have 100 objects. They can be grouped into 3 categories.

Comment: mechanisms are usually countable.

Comment: Does each object have just one generation mechanism?